# How to disable mouse and keyboard read operation from WPF form using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to show information about a customer on a single form with all in text boxes, and other controls disabled from write operations, having a single exit button.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Is there something specific you're having difficulty with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can I please refer you to the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page of the help center?

Comment: It is a huge form with plenty of wpf controls .I don't know the command to disable all field of form except single button ?

Comment: I had to do this before.  I solved it by adding a secondary layer to the root grid which contained the 'next' button, but still let the client see the primary layer.  Visibility controlled by a Vm Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer, as unfortunate as it is, is to add a `bool` property to your view model/code behind and to bind that to the `IsEnabled` property of *every* control that you want to be disabled and then to set that property to `false` when you want to disable them.

```
<Button Content="Something" IsEnabled="{Binding AreControlsEnabled}" />
<Button Content="Something else" IsEnabled="{Binding AreControlsEnabled}" />
<Button Content="Another thing" /> <!--  <<< Will remain enabled   -->
```

In view model/code behind:

```
AreControlsEnabled = false; // <<< Disables controls
```

Comment: It works, but a grid overlay is less wordy.  Did you ever try that?

Comment: getc he, what does that mean and how is it relevant? @GarryVass, I saw your comment and thought that sounds interesting. However, I've never had to disable a large enough number of controls to do that. It might be wise in this case.

Comment: Upvoted, the only amendment I would make to your code is to bind the button to the same variable AreControlsEnabled and use a negation converter.  That allows for 'going back' to the previous state.  All fine.

Comment: Sorry for that comment !! i was looking a term View Model that remind of MVVM framework

Answer (score 0):

If you have a panel for the input fields, then disable that panel and enable just the button you want.

For example, move all your input controls to inside some panel (say `StackPanel`), and keep your button outside the panel. Now disable the stackPanel to get all your input controls disabled.

Comment: -1 That *cannot* be done in WPF... if the containing `Panel` is disabled, the *all* of its children controls will all be disabled too.

Comment: i mean a stackpanel which holds all in the input fields and button should be in different panel or outside the disabled panel.

Comment: I'm happy to remove this down vote once you have added that into your answer... I can't until you make an edit.